# How to display something else when XPath hasn't been found and overwriting previous Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create this app so that it finds the streamers views, if it doesn't find the XPATH I want it to output "Streamer is offline" but it just outputs "Streamer is offline" even for online streamers. Also, when typing a new streamer the label does not overwrite, rather creates a new line.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font
from functools import partial
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time




# Gets the webpage "Twitch" then finds the user inputted and eventually displays the viewer count.
    

def string_twitch(twitchname):
    PATH = "/home/networkmojito/python/Tkinter/chromedriver"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
    options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options = options)
    driver.get("https://twitch.tv/" + twitchname.get())

    try:
        twitch_views = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/p"))
        )
        twitch_viewers = twitch_views.text()
        views_amount = Label(text = "There are currently " + twitch_viewers + " Live viewers in " + twitchname.get() + "'s stream.", fg = 'white', bg = 'black', font = font_ubun_size2)
        views_amount.pack()
    except:
        streamer_offline = Label(text = "Streamer is currently offline.", fg = 'white', bg = 'black', font = font_ubun_size2)
        streamer_offline.pack()
        driver.quit()
        




# creates the window, and "className = x" names the window
window = Tk(className = "Twitch Viewer")

# Window size
window.geometry("700x150")
window.configure(bg = "black")

font_ubun_size = font.Font(size = 28, family = 'Ubuntu Mono')
font_ubun_size2 = font.Font(size = 16, family = 'Ubuntu Mono')

# Username: and also box to enter the username, StringVar, just reveals the text as it is.
user_input = Label(text = "Enter Twitch Username:", fg = "purple", bg = "black", font = font_ubun_size)
user_input.pack()
twitchname = StringVar()
twitch_username = Entry(textvariable = twitchname, bg = '#88979e')
twitch_username.pack()

string_twitch = partial(string_twitch, twitchname)

submit_button = Button(text = "Submit.", fg = "white", bg = "black", activebackground = '#00cc70', activeforeground = 'white', command = string_twitch)
submit_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Create the label outside the function and edit it inside only.

Comment: can you provide an example please, not an answer just a perspective of what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tkinter` we use `config()` to edit properties of created widgets. Here I create the label outside the functions, then I edit it inside the functions only, so over-writing is avoided.

```
def string_twitch(twitchname):
    # Same code
    try:

        .... # same code
        twitch_viewers = twitch_views.text()
        views_amount.config(text="There are currently " + twitch_viewers + " Live viewers in " + twitchname.get() + "'s stream.")
        views_amount.pack()
    except:
        views_amount.config(text = "Streamer is currently offline.")
        views_amount.pack()
        driver.quit()

# Same codes

views_amount = Label(fg='white',bg='black',font=font_ubun_size2) # Make initial widget with common properties
```

A better way to avoid concatenation is to use `f` strings:

```
views_amount.config(text=f"There are currently {twitch_viewers} Live viewers in {twitchname.get()}'s stream.")
```

and so on for other text too.

Plus it is also recommended to pass in the `master` for each widgets so as to avoid confusion when working with multiple windows and so on:

```
user_input = Label(window, text="Enter Twitch Username:", fg="purple", bg="black", font=font_ubun_size)
twitchname = StringVar(window)
twitch_username = Entry(window, textvariable=twitchname, bg='#88979e')
submit_button = Button(window, text="Submit.", fg="white", bg="black", activebackground='#00cc70', activeforeground='white', command=string_twitch)
```

---

However you have asked more than one question here, I have answered the `tkinter` part. For the `selenium` part, you might want to ask a new question - one topic per question is the way to go.

Comment: Well, I think twitch realized I was going on their website, nothing works anymore.

Comment: @Eletrix Sad, hope you find out a solution, this will work for `tkinter`.

Comment: Hopefully, do you know if twitch finds out whether there has been a bot on their server multiple times? And if it blocks from using.

Comment: @Eletrix No, I dont. But I know that you could use a twitch bot, instead of using automation

Comment: I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750049/some-websites-block-selenium-webdriver-how-does-this-work   I tried using it again without the options part and let the browser run, still doesn't work, any ideas/solutions?

Comment: @Eletrix I would suggest to actually make a bot itself, rather than using selenium at all. Im not sure why your getting blocked even when you dont spam anything there.